# Dynamically register classes for Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

Let's say I have this Java RMI method

```java
Optional<Comparable> executeRemotely(CustomAction action) 
   throws NotBoundException, RemoteException {
   // {...}
}
```

And the *client-side* implements a `CustomAction`:

```java
public class Incrementor {
    public Integer complexIncrementor(Integer source){
        // {...}
    }
}

public class IncrementValueAction implements CustomAction {
    
   Integer incrementValue;
   
   public IncrementValueAction(Integer incrementValue) {
     this.incrementValue = incrementValue;
   }
    
   @Override 
   public void execute(Entity entity) {
     Integer count = entity.getProperty("count");
     entity.setProperty("count", new Incrementor().complexIncrementor(count);
   }
}
```

but the class itself is not defined on the server-side of the RMI.

**Call to RMI server**

```
remoteClient.executeRemotely(new IncrementLikesAction(1000));
```

How do you *dynamically* register `Incrementor` class used so the server-side would be able to use the class when the `CustomAction` executes?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the type returned by method `executeRemotely()`. What is `Comporable` ?

Comment: _Let's say I have this Java RMI method_ That would mean that `executeRemotely()` is a method declared in an interface that extends `java.rmi.Remote`, correct?

Comment: You are looking for the RMI Codebase feature, where in this case the client provides the codebase.